# This class (or a class which this class inherits from) is marked as '@imutable' but one or more of its instance fields are not final

Tags: flutter, dart

I get this warning in Android Studio in **stateless** widget

> This class (or a class which this class inherits from) is marked as
>   '@imutable' but one or more of its instance fields are not final

when I want to create variable outside of build method. How do I get rid of this warning... or am I doing something wrong?

**Replicable code**

```
class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> list = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'name1'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'name2'}
  ];
  List<int> _ids = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _ids.clear();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: list.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  _ids.add(list[index]['id']);
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(list[index]['name']),
                  );
                }),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Print all ids'),
            onPressed: () {
              print(_ids.toString());
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**peace of that warning message**

[image]

Comment: Immutable means a class that is initialized once including all class variables. Once it is initialized it can be never altered. Immutable classes are guaranteed to be thread safe! Be careful in any approach on changing state here.

Comment: @MartinStrejc I've just edited my code with better example so what would be your approach in this case. Where would you place `_ids` variable to get rid of that warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to mark both list to final. You can still add and remove elements from your lists but you cannot re-initialize them.

**You can**

```
list.add('c')
```

**You can't**

```
list = ['apple']
```

In your case the correct code would look like this:

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  Final List<String> list = ['a', 'b'];
  Final List<int> _ids = [];
```

Comment: ups sorry.. I can actually